# Is there dry_run functionality in FCM?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

GCM has `dry_run` [functionality](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table1):

> This parameter, when set to true, allows developers to test a request
>   without actually sending a message.

GCM is being deprecated in favor of [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages), but I don't see a similar feature in FCM.

Does FCM allow you to do a dry run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The `dry_run` feature is still available [for FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) (Legacy).

Answer (score 5):

AL's answer is based on the FCM Legacy.
For FCM v1, this option is called `validate_only`

You can see the documentation here: [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send)